# Creating multiple workbooks from a single Excel worksheet in R

Tags: r, excel, vba, subset

I have a single worksheet in excel that I want to break into multiple separate workbooks using the values of a specific column, in R.

Below is an example tibble:

```
    g0 = tibble(
  Area = c("North","North","North","North","North","North"),
  School = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
  Student_ID = c(134,221,122,126,128,156),
  test_score_a = c(24,26,22,25,55,58),
  test_score_b = c(31,33,21,25,78,87),
  test_score_c = c(29,85,75,55,23,56))
```

If the data in the tibble above were to be in a single excel sheet, I am trying to learn how to create multiple excel files based on the data in variable 'School'. And each file would include the corresponding name of the school.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must correct the example because the `School` variable has more rows than the others. Then, try this:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(split(g0,g0$School),"my_excel.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If I understand this correctly, the code you suggested is to split 1 excel worksheet into separate worksheets in the same excel workbook. I am looking to make separate worksheets (separate excel files).